# how to integrate reward extension in a magento code

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

I have an issue how to integrate extension in a Magento, extension work fine in a website, I want to do same functionality from outside the Magento programmatically. Suppose I am using add to cart code , how i am using this extension in it

```
   <?php
   $id = '100'; // Replace id with your product id
   $qty = '2'; // Replace qty with your qty
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
   $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
   $cart->init();
   $cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
   $cart->save();
   Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with the following lines of code.

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// Now you can run ANY Magento code you want

// Change 12 to the ID of the product you want to load
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(12);

echo $_product->getName();
```

This was only a quick post but hopefully it will be useful.

Here's an example how to get the site navigation.

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$_layout  = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$_block   = $_layout->createBlock('catalog/navigation')->setTemplate('catalog/navigation/left.phtml');

echo $_block->toHtml();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply , my question is how reward point extension use in add to cart code. because reward can override the cart , its add reward in a summary calculation.